# How to train data correctly using libsvm?

Tags: java, svm, libsvm

I want to use SVM (Support vector machine) in my program, but I could not get the true result.

I want to know that how we must train data for SVM.

What I am doing:

Think that we have 5 document (the numbers are just an example), 3 of them is on first category and others (2 of them) are on second category, I merge the categories to each other (it means that the 3 doc that are in the first category will merge in one document), after that I made a train array like this:

```
double[][] train = new double[cat1.getDocument().getAttributes().size() + cat2.getDocument().getAttributes().size()][];
```

and I will fill the array like this:

```
int i = 0;
    Iterator<String> iteraitor = cat1.getDocument().getAttributes().keySet().iterator();
    Iterator<String> iteraitor2 = cat2.getDocument().getAttributes().keySet().iterator();
    while (i < train.length) {
        if (i < cat2.getDocument().getAttributes().size()) {
            while (iteraitor2.hasNext()) {
                String key = (String) iteraitor2.next();
                Long value = cat2.getDocument().getAttributes().get(key);
                double[] vals = { 0, value };
                train[i] = vals;
                i++;
                System.out.println(vals[0] + "," + vals[1]);
            }
        } else {
            while (iteraitor.hasNext()) {
                String key = (String) iteraitor.next();
                Long value = cat1.getDocument().getAttributes().get(key);
                double[] vals = { 1, value };
                train[i] = vals;
                i++;
                System.out.println(vals[0] + "," + vals[1]);
            }
            i++;
        }
```

so I will continue like this to get the model :

```
svm_problem prob = new svm_problem();
    int dataCount = train.length;
    prob.y = new double[dataCount];
    prob.l = dataCount;
    prob.x = new svm_node[dataCount][];

    for (int k = 0; k < dataCount; k++) {
        double[] features = train[k];
        prob.x[k] = new svm_node[features.length - 1];
        for (int j = 1; j < features.length; j++) {
            svm_node node = new svm_node();
            node.index = j;
            node.value = features[j];
            prob.x[k][j - 1] = node;
        }
        prob.y[k] = features[0];
    }
    svm_parameter param = new svm_parameter();
    param.probability = 1;
    param.gamma = 0.5;
    param.nu = 0.5;
    param.C = 1;
    param.svm_type = svm_parameter.C_SVC;
    param.kernel_type = svm_parameter.LINEAR;
    param.cache_size = 20000;
    param.eps = 0.001;
    svm_model model =  svm.svm_train(prob, param);
```

Is this way correct? if not please help me to make it true.

---

these two answers are true : [answer one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21281112/2034653) , [answer two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21293974/2034653),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even without examining the code one can find conceptual errors:

> think that we have 5 document , 3 of them is on first category and others( 2 of them) are on second category , i merge the categories to each other (it means that the 3 doc that are in the first category will merge in one document ) ,after that i made a train array like this

So:

- training on the 5 documents won't give any reasonable effects, with any machine learning model... these are **statistical** models,there is no reasonable statistics in 5 points in R^n, where n~10,000
- You **do not** merge anything. Such approach can work for Naive Bayes, which do not really treat documents as "whole" but rather - as probabilistic dependencies between features and classes. In SVM each document should be **separate** point in the R^n space, where n can be number of distinct words (for bag of words/set of words representation).

Comment: thank you @lejlot ,the numbers just for describing, the real numbers are more than these numbers,and it means that i should put each document separately in my train array? if you could please show me with an example

Comment: Yes each document is a separate element. There are **milions** examples online, asking for a code for such thing shows complete lack of engagement. There is no difference between using SVM with documents and with any other kind of data. Using the vectorization you translate each of your documents into **vectors**. Once done, **any** example of SVM will work.

Answer (score 2):

A problem might be that you do not terminate each set of features in a training example with an index of -1 which you should according to the read me...

I.e. if you have one example with two features i think you should do:

```
Index[0]: 0
Value[0]: 22
Index[1]: 1
Value[1]: 53
Index[2]: -1
```

Good luck!

Comment: Termination of "-1" is afaik not needed (if you take a look on the example data-sets online)...

Answer (score 2):

Using SVMs to classify text is a common task. You can check out research papers by Joachims [1] regarding SVM text classification.

Basically you have to:

1. Tokenize your documents
2. Remove stopwords
3. Apply stemming technique
4. Apply feature selection technique (see [2])
5. Transform your documents using features achieved in 4.) (simple would be binary (0: feature is absent, 1: feature is present) or other measures like TFC)
6. Train your SVM and be happy :)

[1] T. Joachims: Text Categorization with Support Vector Machines: Learning with Many Relevant Features; Springer: Heidelberg, Germany, 1998, doi:10.1007/BFb0026683.

[2] Y. Yang, J. O. Pedersen: A Comparative Study on Feature Selection in Text Categorization. International Conference on Machine Learning, 1997, 412-420.